# Is there a library for notification/alert in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, notifications, alerts

I need to design a notifications framework written solely in .Net. I was wondering is there were some libraries already available to ease in creating rules for the notifications.

PS: Anything other than SQL Server Notifications please.

Note: Notifications as in Emails and SMS notifications.

Comment: What do you mean with "notifications"? There are "events" in .NET you know...

Comment: I don't think that's what he's talking about :)

Comment: does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177/notification-api-for-windows help?

Comment: Me neither, but what is it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sort of shopping around for some solutions as well. If understand you correctly, you want to do what is also called "Publish/Subscribe." This can also be done with something called an "Enterprise Service Bus." There are other methods like MSMQ and so forth. There are some articles in Patterns and Practices on doing Publish/Subscribe and building an ESB with WCF.

Here's a blog post discussing rolling your own ESB with WCF:

http://www.iserviceoriented.com/blog/post/Building+Our+Own+ESB+-+Publish+Subscribe+Part+1.aspx

Juval Löwy's book: Programming WCF also has some discussion of doing Publish Subscribe in WCF.

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-WCF-Services-Juval-Lowy/dp/0596526997](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526997)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's worth looking to frameworks like Windows Live Alerts: http://dev.live.com/alerts/